# pam_get_uid; no such user

Tags: rhel, pam, postgresql

I am seeing this error when an app server is trying to access to a postgres database on the RHEL 6 server.

```
authentication: pam_succeed_if(postgresql:auth): error retrieving information about user svc-flow
authentication: pam_tally2(postgresql:auth): pam_get_uid; no such user
```

the account accesses the db with no issues. but the error occurring every second so just filling up `/var/log/secure` file quickly so I would like to find a way to resolve the error.

I googled for any direction but couldn't find a good one.

Looking for any suggestion here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After some further investigation, I suspected the error gets generated because the user doesn't exist locally on the system although the user authentication is processed with AD.

So I created the user locally on the server, then confirmed the error is not generated any more.